# How to query in GraphQL with no fixed input object contents?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I want to query to get a string, for which I have to provide a input object, however the input data can have multiple optional keys and quite grow large as well. So I just wanted something like `Object` as data type while defining schema.

```
// example of supposed schema

  input SampleInput {
    id: ID
    data: Object  // such thing not exist, wanted something like this. 
  }

  type Query {
    myquery(input: SampleInput!): String
  }
```

here `data` input can be quite large so I do not want to define a `type` for it. is there a way around this?

Comment: 'custom JSON scalar'

Comment: @xadm thanks man!, I got to learn about scalars now.